# InitScript Debian Insserv not starting on boot

Tags: linux, jar, debian, boot, init

I got a problem with an Initscript on my Cubietruck working on Cubian (Debian Wheezy)
I want to make an executable Jarfile start after booting.

Therefore i created the following ShellScript to start my jar (/usr/local/bin/startplt.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
JAVA=/usr/bin/java
JARFILE=/home/cubie/plt.jar
USER=cubie
/bin/su - $USER -c "$JAVA -jar $JARFILE &"
```

Running this script from console works.

Then I created another scriptfile working as a service to start/stop my Javaapplication. It should be written like the skeleton template but i did not get anything of that skeleton file. Here is my service (/etc/init.d/startjar)

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          startjar
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:     5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts plt.jar
# Description:       starts a the main jarfile
### END INIT INFO

NAME="startjar"
DESC="Starts /home/cubie/plt.jar"

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

case "$1" in
 start)
    /usr/local/bin/startplt.sh
    ;;
 stop)
    pkill -f /home/cubie/plt.jar
    pkill -f iceweasel
    ;;
 *)
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

The Jar is starting Iceweasel to show some Data thats why its killed onStop.
Starting and stopping of this script via console works with:

```
/etc/init.d/startjar start
/etc/init.d/startjar stop
```

As well as adding to services

```
insserv -d  /etc/init.d/startjar
```

But after the boot nothing happens at all.
Im not very familiar with runlevels and the required-stop/start variables
actually not with shell scripting in general.
I dont really see what am i doing wrong or what my scripts are missing :(

Can anyone tell me what i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have your service configured to start in runlevel 5, but Debian boots into runlevel 2 by default. This is probably why it doesn't start your service.

Modify `Default-Start` to include 2, then run `update-rc.d startjar defaults` or similar.

Incidentally, I think this question should be moved to serverfault.

Comment: i thought runlevels would be like a specific state and runlevel 5 is reached too. nevertheless i edited the default-start to 2 3 4 5 -> insserv -d /etc/init.d/startjar -> reboot -> still nothing

Comment: Please check whether a symlink to your startjar initscript exists in /etc/rc2.d. E.g. `ls -l /etc/rc2.d/S??startjar`.

Comment: sorry i cant check that i was reseting the stuff i did in order to have a stable enviroment

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help but i got another working solution by myself.

I created a desktop entry in `/home/cubie/.config/autostart/` which starts my jar now after the xsession. im